# WCF as MVC controller. model and views?

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller

I've been searching on the net for possible answer to my question, but no luck at all.
I just wonder if I could use WCF as my Controller in ASP.NET MVC.

So if I call
(WCF)
    http://localhost:1621/WCF/LogOut.svc?id=10001

It will work like
(MVC)
    http://localhost:1621/WCF/LogOut?id=10001

Or I'm just having wrong thought about it?
Can you give some source for deeper knowledge in MVC and WCF.. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this as WCF and MVC controllers are designed for very different purposes?

Comment: actually, I have a web site made in ASP.Net MVC3. Now someone told me to put it on WCF? I'm completely having no idea on how to do it. We are hosting WCF projects (made) in azure, to save more money, we compile all projects in one, in the form of WCF. So that is why I'm asking for possibilities of joining my MVC project in WCF. I can't explain it well coz truly I can't understand what has to be done. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MVC states that the controller picks up requests and it is responsible for preparing the model and passing it to a view which is ultimately rendered.

Although from the perspective of web requests, WCF could possibly *look like* MVC, there is no easy way to make WCF render the HTML to the browser. This means that if WCF can implement "controllers" which produce "models" but is not designed to create "views".

However, if your web application can pick up XML/JSON data produced by WCF calls (i.e. you have your views implemented purely at the client side) then yes, WCF does a good job as a provider of the "controller/model" part of the MVC.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now at least I have an idea on what to do.